# Python subprocess.call on ffprob errors

Tags: python, ffprobe

I have an error executing line of code that successfully parses outside of python:

```
import subprocess

heightstring = '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 ' + "'" + join(src_dir, 'Test_V1.mov') + "'"
print(heightstring)
height = subprocess.call(heightstring)
```

When I run the result of the print(heightstring) from the terminal, I get the correct value. What is going on?

```
Sashas-iMac:2018.03.20 test sasha$ python run.py
/usr/local/bin/ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 '/Users/sasha/Downloads/demo-videos-src/Test_V1.mov'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 274, in <module>
    height = subprocess.call(heightstring)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Sashas-iMac:2018.03.20 test sasha$ /usr/local/bin/ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1 '/Users/sasha/Downloads/demo-videos-src/Test_V1.mov'
1080
Sashas-iMac:2018.03.20 test sasha$
```

the error is confusing, as it says no such file or directory, but the file exists as it is clearly shows by the second command execution directly from the terminal. I also included a full path, to the ffprobe as well as to the video file.

Comment: possibly due to the one / instead of the //

Comment: thank you Mit, just tried and got same result, except with // printed out, but the error is the same - no such file...

Comment: looking again at your printed path ("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py") it looks like it's missing something, don't yoy think? is that location on a spicific local drive? should it have that in the path?

Comment: not really sure I understand your suggestion, sorry.
This path is pertained to subprocess.py which is successfully found by the python interpreter. This is internal call and error displayed on a screen. What failing is I believe that the subprocess is trying to load my external file, but I do provide full path to that video file.